# Plot axis of different lengths and then lines

Tags: r

Ok, I'm really struggling with this. I've tried to read various answers on StackOverflow but didn't find te solution. So here it is:

I have clients ids, and have time of operations. I also have time intervals associated with clients waiting in the queue. I want to plot lines representing the clients waiting time onto the plot where xlab: hours of operations, ylab: client.

Data:

```
 [1] "2011-05-12 08:00:00 " "2011-05-12 09:00:00 "
 [3] "2011-05-12 10:00:00 " "2011-05-12 11:00:00 "
 [5] "2011-05-12 12:00:00 " "2011-05-12 13:00:00 "
 [7] "2011-05-12 14:00:00 " "2011-05-12 15:00:00 "
 [9] "2011-05-12 16:00:00 " "2011-05-12 17:00:00 "
[11] "2011-05-12 18:00:00 " "2011-05-12 19:00:00 "
[13] "2011-05-12 20:00:00 "
```

by the way, have two questions here:
1. is there any convinient way to store time without date? Like "19:00:00" 
2. How can I create seq of time with min

```
clients[1:10]
 [1] G155 H54  G157 G158 J52  A51  C52  D52  G151 Y51
```

Then I have time for every client:

```
xcl[1:3,]
             StartTime            NextTime             EndTime TrackNo
33 2011-04-29 19:15:57 2011-04-29 19:20:04 2011-04-29 19:23:13    G155
34 2011-04-29 19:16:06 2011-04-29 19:25:41 2011-04-29 19:26:13     H54
36 2011-04-29 19:45:56 2011-04-29 19:47:58 2011-04-29 19:48:42    G157
```

So I can calc the waiting time and time of operation. I want to draw horizontal lines to represent that. How am I to do it?

[image: Should be somth like this]

Comment: Have a look at the very last `gantt.chart` example in `plotrix` package. Maybe something for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="StartTime,NextTime,EndTime,TrackNo
33,2011-04-29 19:15:57,2011-04-29 19:20:04,2011-04-29 19:23:13,G155
34,2011-04-29 19:16:06,2011-04-29 19:25:41,2011-04-29 19:26:13,H54
36,2011-04-29 19:45:56,2011-04-29 19:47:58,2011-04-29 19:48:42,G157", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#make datetimes POSXct objects
DF[,1:3] <- do.call(cbind.data.frame,lapply(DF[,1:3], as.POSIXct, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT"))

#discard date information
DF <- cbind(DF, do.call(cbind.data.frame,lapply(DF[,1:3], function(x) as.POSIXct(format(x, "%H:%M:%S"), format="%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT"))))
names(DF)[5:7] <- paste0(names(DF)[5:7],1)

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(DF, aes(y=TrackNo, yend=TrackNo)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=StartTime1, xend=NextTime1), colour="red", size=2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=NextTime1, xend=EndTime1), colour="green", size=2) +
  theme_classic(base_size=23) +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("")

print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Roland, that is awesome! You solved my issues so elegantly. I've thought of ggplot but didn't figure that it's so powerful and efficient and easy-understandable. Thanks again!